# logical matrix how to find efficiently row/column with true value

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures, time-complexity

I'm trying to find a efficient solution for the next riddle:

1. i have a logical matrix at (**n * n**) size filled in **false** values
2. i need to create a function that will get zero or one as argument **it will shift all
   the values in the matrix one step to the left** (meaning the first
   element on the first row is deleted and the last element in the last
   row is our new bit) and **return true if there is a row/column in our
   matrix contains only one's values.**

No limitation on the data structure.

My naive solution in javascript:

```
const next = (bit, matrix) => {
  matrix.shift()
  matrix.push(bit);

  const matrix_size = Math.sqrt(matrix.length);

  let col_sum = 0;
  let row_sum = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
    col_sum = matrix[i];
    row_sum += matrix[i];

    if ((i + 1) % matrix_size === 0) {
      if (row_sum === matrix_size) return true;

      row_sum = 0;
    }

    for (let j = i + matrix_size;j < (i + ((matrix_size * matrix_size) - 1)); j += matrix_size) {
      col_sum += matrix[j];
    }

    if (col_sum === matrix_size) return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

i used 1d array as data structure but it doesn't really help my to reduce time complexity.

Love to hear some ideas :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s think about following example matrix:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 1, 1,
 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

and push zero 16 times.
Then, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, False, False False and False will be obtained.
There is cyclic behavior (False, True, True, True).
If the length of continued ones was fixed, it isn’t necessary to recalculate every time in update.
Updated the matrix, the length of continued ones at top-left and bottom-right can be change, and it can be needed to update the cyclic memory.
Maintaining continued ones sequences, maintaining total count of cyclic behavior affected by the sequences, the complexity for the rows will be in `O(1)`.

In case of column, instead of shifting and pushing, let `matrix[cur]=bit` and `cur = (cur+1)%(matrix_size*matrix_size)` to represent `cur` as the actual upper-left of the matrix.
Maintaining col_sum of each column, maintaining total count satisfying the all-ones-condition, the complexity will be `O(1)`.

```py
class Matrix:
  def __init__(self, n):
    self.mat = [0] * (n*n)
    self.seq_len = [0] * (n*n)
    self.col_total = [0] * n
    self.col_archive = 0
    self.row_cycle_cnt = [0] * n
    self.cur = 0
    self.continued_one = 0
    self.n = n

  def update(self, bit):
    prev_bit = self.mat[self.cur]
    self.mat[self.cur] = bit

    # update col total
    col = self.cur % self.n
    if self.col_total[col] == self.n:
      self.col_archive -= 1
    self.col_total[col] += bit - prev_bit
    if self.col_total[col] == self.n:
      self.col_archive += 1

    # update row index
    # process shift out
    if prev_bit == 1:
      prev_len = self.seq_len[self.cur]
      if prev_len > 1:
        self.seq_len[(self.cur + 1) % (self.n * self.n)] = prev_len-1
      if self.n <= prev_len and prev_len < self.n*2:
        self.row_cycle_cnt[self.cur % self.n] -= 1
    # process new bit
    if bit == 0:
      self.continued_one = 0
    else:
      self.continued_one = min(self.continued_one + 1, self.n*self.n)
      # write the length of continued_one at the head of sequence
      self.seq_len[self.cur+1 - self.continued_one] = self.continued_one
      if self.n <= self.continued_one and self.continued_one < self.n*2:
        self.row_cycle_cnt[(self.cur+1) % self.n] += 1

    # update cursor
    self.cur = (self.cur + 1) % (self.n * self.n)

    return (self.col_archive > 0) or (self.row_cycle_cnt[self.cur % self.n] > 0)

  def check2(self):
    for y in range(self.n):
      cnt = 0
      for x in range(self.n):
        cnt += self.mat[(self.cur + y*self.n + x) % (self.n*self.n)]
      if cnt == self.n:
        return True
    for x in range(self.n):
      cnt = 0
      for y in range(self.n):
        cnt += self.mat[(self.cur + y*self.n + x) % (self.n*self.n)]
      if cnt == self.n:
        return True
    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
  import random
  random.seed(123)
  m = Matrix(4)
  for i in range(100000):
    ans1 = m.update(random.randint(0, 1))
    ans2 = m.check2()
    assert(ans1 == ans2)
    print("epoch:{} mat={} ans={}".format(i, m.mat[m.cur:] + m.mat[:m.cur], ans1))
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks !!:)

Comment: @YochaiAkoka and machy (and any other reader who can help) I'm confused :) Just looking at rows, for example - if we have an N*N matrix, and we have an arbitrary number of different blocks of N continuous 1s that started at the bottom right with no timed pattern, how do we keep track in O(1) of which one of these continuous blocks may be occupying a full row at any time? Could you please demonstrate?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I've appended code, even though not enough commented... The code is written on the base idea. In case of matrix with 4x4 size, growing ones sequence from 3 to 4 affects the cyclic behavior, 4 to 5, 5 to 6, 6 to 7 also affects, but 7 to 8 doesn't affect. Because ones sequence longer or equal to 7 makes the condition True anytime. `if self.n <= self.continued_one and self.continued_one < self.n*2:` reflects this idea.

Comment: This answer is so brilliant. I would vote a second time if I could :)